# python: array default value for index out-of-bounds

Tags: python, arrays

I need a good way to ask for an array/matrix value, but reporting a default (0) value for out-of-bound index:
b[2][4] should return 0 if the 2nd index length is 3, and
b[-1][2] also
I checked this:
[Getting a default value on index out of range in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574636/getting-a-default-value-on-index-out-of-range-in-python), but it seems to me that it would not work for negative indices - since python always add the array length to them (true?)
I was thinking along the line of overloading `__getitem__`, but I just came to python 1 month ago, and I'm not so skilled...

any help appreciated!

alessandro

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want a indefinitely-sized sparse matrix, you can use defautldict:

```
py> matrix=defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(lambda:0))
py> matrix[2][4]
0
py> matrix[2][4]=8
py> matrix[2][4]
8
py> matrix[-1][2]
0
```

Comment: +1 for sparse "array" == dict.  I'm a fan of using just a single dict (rather than nested) with tuples for keys, e.g. `matrix[2, 4]`.

Comment: @Ben: I agree, tuples make better indices in two-dimensional arrays. However, having the indices separate was a requirement in the OP's question.

Comment: — Oh, I wasn't picking nits over your answer, this just seemed the natural place to make the suggestion.  :-)

Comment: You could also do `defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))` - `int() is 0`.

Comment: @Ben Blank - I was not aware that was valid Python syntax... thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your confusing the issue.

`listy[-1]` is a *relative* index such that, the true index equals len(listy),

`listy[-2]` true index is len(listy) -1, ... and so on

If the relative index does not exist it will still raise an `IndexError`.  Such as this: `[][0]` or this `[1][-2]`

Answer (score 0):

> since python always add the array length to them (true?)

The built-in Python sequences do this, but as far as I can tell it's done by those sequences' implementations, not by the Python compiler. So no, you'll receive negative values in your `__getitem__` (or `__getslice__`) and can handle them as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

for general knowledge, the usage of **getitem** and **setitem** is this:

(inside object class)

```
def __getitem__(self,index):
    print index
    return self.mylist[index]

def __setitem__(self,index,value):
    self.mylist[index]=value
```

if you override the list class ( `class newListClass(list):` ), and want to use the getitem of the list inside your own getitem, you need to write:

```
class newListClass(list):
    def __getitem__(self,index):
        return list.__getitem__(self,index)
```

this way you can also catch exception from this **getitem** and return what you want instead.
that's not an answer for your problem, Martin's is.. but you interested in the **getitem** usage, so thats the way to do it.
enjoy :)