# Does python have a built-in get() for list similar to dictionaries?

Tags: python

I would like to pluck an item from a list and return a default if not found (instead of usual index exception).  Very similar to get(key, default) on a dictionary.  After perusing the docs, it feels like I still overlooked a trivial built-in python solution that provides this.

Here's the fastest I could come up with:

```
def pluck(list_items, index, default=None):
  return dict(zip(range(len(list_items)), list_items)).get(index, default)

s = [1, 2,]
pluck(s, 3, None)
```

Thanks!

Comment: One point, you should read up on `enumerate`.  It's much nicer to look at than `zip(range(len....`.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  Your solution should work, but it seems like creating a new `dict` carries a lot of extra work as opposed to one of these solutions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574636/getting-a-default-value-on-index-out-of-range-in-python

Comment: I think `return list_items[item] if index < len(list_items) else default` is best solution

Comment: @rpq: What about negative indices?

Comment: @martineau `return list_items[item] if 0 <= item < len(list_items) else default`

Comment: @martineau: Valid point.  My particular use case was for positive indexes only.  I was hoping for an answer that was exactly one Python built-in method or function (similar to get() on dict).  If it handled both negative and positive indexes, great, if not, great too.

Comment: @austin: i've read dict() is actually slower than {} as well.

Comment: @rpq: There's no built-in so you'll have to roll-your-own. IMHO Sylvain's answers are the best as they handle both positive and negative index values.

Comment: It looks like the answer is no. :)  But the answers were awesome +1'd

Comment: Seriously if you're going to accept such answers then don't waste out time by  posting questions here.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on how often you expect to try to access outside of the bounds of the array, you either should catch the exception (if failures are expected to be rare), or test that the index is valid and otherwise return the default value.

If failures are expected to be rare, this should probably be the fastest solution:

```
def pluck(items, index, defval):
    try:
        return items[index]
    except IndexError:
        return defval
```

If they are expected to be frequent, it is better to check that the index is valid:

```
def pluck(items, index, defval):
    return items[index] if -len(items) <= index < len(items) else defval
```

Note that this using negative indexes is valid if `abs(index) <= len(items)`, ie. `items[-1]` is equivalent to `items[len(items)-1]`.

Comment: This is a separate point, but does the double comparison a<x<b work in python? I thought it didn't.

Comment: Yes, it has the expected meaning (as in math): http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in

Answer (score 3):

To keep it really fast and simple, if you are using only positive indexes:

```
seq, i = [1, 2, 3], 2
plucked = seq[i] if seq[i:] else None
```

Otherwise:

```
def pluck(seq, index, default=None):
    try:
        return seq[index]
    except IndexError:
        return default
```

if exceptions are the norm:

```
def pluck(seq, index, default=None):
    return seq[index] if seq[index:] and seq[-index-1:] else default
```

Both work for negative indexes.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, it works for negative indexes as well.

```
def list_get(lis, index, default = None):
   index = index if index >=0 else len(lis) + index
   return lis[index] if 0 <= index < len(lis) else default

>>> lis = range(10)
>>> list_get(lis, 8, 'foo')
8
>>> list_get(lis, 11, 'foo')
'foo'
>>> list_get(lis, -11, 'foo')
'foo'
>>> list_get(lis, -9, 'foo')
1
>>> list_get(lis, -5, 'foo')
5
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your pluck function can be written as

```
def pluck(list_items, index, default=None):
  if index>length(list_items)-1
     return default
   else 
      return list_items[index]
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'list_items' object has no attribute 'length'`

Comment: Ok, maybe length(list_items)?