# how do i assign a default value if no argument is passed in + python

Tags: python

**How do I write `letter = sys.argv[2] or 'a'` so that if there is no argument passed in `a` will be assigned to letter.**  So basically I want the default value of `letter` to be `a` unless something is passed in. If something is to be passed in, I want that to be assigned to `letter`

this is my simple program:

```
$ cat loop_count.py
import sys

def count(word,letter):
        for char in word:
                if char == letter:
                        count = count + 1
        return count
                                # WHAT I WANT
word = sys.argv[1] or 'banana'  # if sys.argv[1] has a value assign it to word, else assign 'banana' to word
letter = sys.argv[2] or 'a'     # if sys.argv[2] has a value assign it to letter, else assign 'a' to letter

print 'Count the number of times the letter',letter,' appears in the word: ', word

count = 0
for letter in word:
        if letter == 'a':
                count = count + 1
print count
```

This is me running the program by passing it 2 arguments `pea` and `a`

```
$ python loop_count.py pea a
Count the number of times the letter a  appears in the word:  pea
1
```

I want the arguments to be optional so I was hoping the letter arguemt does not have to be passed.  **So how do I write `letter = sys.argv[2] or 'a'` so that if there is no argument passed in letter will be assigned to `a`**

This is me running the program with only one argument, I want the arguments to be optional.

```
$ python loop_count.py pea
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "loop_count.py", line 10, in <module>
    letter = sys.argv[2] or 'a'
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a default value on index out of range in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574636/getting-a-default-value-on-index-out-of-range-in-python)

Answer (score 10):

You can use the following:

```
letter = sys.argv[2] if len(sys.argv) >= 3 else 'a'
```

`sys.argv[2]` is the 3rd element in `sys.argv`, this means that the length of `sys.argv` should be at least 3. If it is not `>= 3`, we assign `'a'` to `letter`

Comment: tks thats it, but is there a shorter way to write that like `letter = sys.argv[2] ? len(sys.argv) : 'a'` or is that java sccript?

Comment: That's the equivalent of tirnary operator in Python and it is the shorter possible way.