# Implementing a list equivalent of the default feature offered by `dict.get`

Tags: python, list, inheritance

`dict`s have a convenient version of the `get`:

> `get(key[, default])`
>
> Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. **If
>   default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this method never
>   raises a `KeyError`.**

Bold emphasis mine, because I looked and could not find an equivalent version for lists. So I implemented my own:

```
In [148]: class myList(list):
     ...:     def pop(self, idx=-1, default=None):
     ...:         try:
     ...:             return super().pop(idx)
     ...:         except IndexError:
     ...:             return default
```

This works as expected:

```
In [149]: l = myList([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

In [150]: l.pop()
Out[150]: 5

In [151]: l.pop(12345, 'default')
Out[151]: 'default'
```

Since this works, this can also be extended to sets. Anyway, I've got a couple of questions:

1. Is there an easier/inbuilt/3rd party equivalent to what I've done that doesn't require me to extend the `list` class?
2. If there isn't, is there any particular reason why? I believe this would be a useful behaviour to have.

Some particular use cases I can think of would be calling `pop` on a list whose size you don't know, in a place you don't want to, or can't catch errors, such as a list comp.

---

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574636) explores the same topic but the answers do not suit my requirement, as I have explained above.

Comment: It cannot be extended to sets because sets are not *indexed*. In sets there is `discard` instead, that discards an item by equality - as the item would have been equal to the value used as the argument to discard, there is little use.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Just the default behaviour, not the index. Sets also have a `pop` method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a default value on index out of range in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574636/getting-a-default-value-on-index-out-of-range-in-python)

Comment: Sets have the `pop` method yes, which pops the first element by iteration order - but frankly I am not sure what you would gain by having a default there...

Comment: @JohanL Yes I know about EAFP. I wanted to know if there is a convenience method as offered by `dict.get`.

Comment: Personally, I only ever use `list.pop(0)` and `list.pop(-1)`, and have never found myself needing to supply a default (there are other, simpler ways to handle an empty list).

Comment: Did you mean `dict.pop` instead of `dict.get`? `pop` and `get` aren't equivalent to each other. Plus `return super().pop(idx)` can be replaced with `return self[idx]`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary No I did not. I was only comparing the two in terms of the default argument returned.

Comment: How about `lst[idx:] and lst.pop(idx)`, or some variant on this ?

Comment: @Chris_Rands Do you mean `(lst[idx:] and lst.pop(idx)) or default`? Because if you do, that's brilliant.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yah, that's the one

Comment: @Chris_Rands Please write an answer, a couple of example if you wish.

Comment: @Chris_Rands Won't work with falsy values.

Comment: oh damn :-( ... I liked the look of that.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary is right of course, just spotted that too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One reason why it is only implemented for dictionaries is that checking `if key in some_dict` isn't always an `O(1)` operation in the worst case it could be `O(n)`. But even if the lookup is `O(1)` it's actually an expensive operation because you need to hash the key, then if there's a match you need to compare the key to the stored key for equality. That makes [LBYL](https://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-lbyl) very expensive for dictionaries.

For lists on the other hand checking that the index is within bounds is a quite inexpensive operation. I mean you could check if it's within bounds with a simple:

```
valid_index = -len(some_list) <= index < len(some_list)
```

But that's just for LBYL approaches. One could always use [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-eafp) and catch the Exception.

That should be impose the same overhead to lists and dicts. So why has `dict` a `get` method to avoid exception handling? The reason is actually quite simple: `dict`s are the fundamental building blocks of almost everything. Most classes and all modules are essentially just dictionaries and a lot of user code actually uses dictionaries. It was (and still is) just worth it to have a method that can do a guaranteed return without the exception handling overhead.

For lists it could be useful too (I'm not so sure on that point) but I think in most cases when it throws an `IndexError` it happened accidentally, not on purpose. So it would hide a real "bug" if it would return `None`s.

That's just my reasoning about this. I could be that the Python developers had completely different reasons for the current behavior.

---

#### Regarding your first question:

> Is there an easier/inbuilt/3rd party equivalent to what I've done that doesn't require me to extend the list class?

Also I don't know a standard library or 3rd party module for these operations with defaults for lists or sets. Some libraries implement a "sparse list" (a list filled with a default value) but those I've looked at don't handle the "empty list" case and they use **one default** for the complete list.

However there could be some options that might be interesting in case you don't want to do the "exception handling" yourself:

- The `iter_except` recipe from the [`itertools` documentation page](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) which stops to call a function when a specified exception occurs:

  ```
  def iter_except(func, exception, first=None):
      # Copied verbatim from the above mentioned documentation page
      try:
          if first is not None:
              yield first()
          while True:
              yield func()
      except exception:
          pass

  >>> l = [1,2,3,4]
  >>> list(iter_except(l.pop, IndexError))
  [4, 3, 2, 1]
  ```
- [`contextlib.suppress`](https://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress)

  ```
  import contextlib
  def pop_with_default(lst, ind=-1, default=None):
      with contextlib.suppress(IndexError):
          return lst.pop(ind)
      return default

  >>> pop_with_default([1,2,3], 5, 'abc')
  'abc'
  ```

Another way to deal with the general problem here is to create a function that calls another function and in case of a specified exception will return a default value otherwise the result of the function call:

```
def call_with_default(func, default=None, *exceptions):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            res = func(*args, **kwargs)
        except exceptions:
            res = default
        return res
    return inner

>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> a_pop_with_default = call_with_default(a.pop, 'abc', IndexError)
>>> [a_pop_with_default(2) for _ in range(10)]
[3, 4, 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc']
```

Comment: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/1999-July/000580.html and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.lang.python/6xRvGCCrYXs/iDZi4MZcMboJ

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I only found some libs implementing a sparse list but these use a global default and don't handle the case when the list is empty and you want to `pop` an item. But there is one thing that could be interesting in case you want to stop a comprehension when an exception is raised `iter_except` ([`itertools` "recipes" section](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)). Likewise there is [`contextlib.suppress`](https://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress). But these don't handle the "default" case so they may not be appropriate here.

Answer (score 1):

Why couldn't you use something simple like this?

```
my_list.pop(n) if n < len(my_list) else "default"
```

**EDIT**

Good comments.  What are your thoughts about something like this?

```
def list_popper(my_list, idx=-1, default='default'):
    try:
        default = my_list.pop(idx)
    except IndexError:
        return default
```

The functionality is the same as the OP's class inheritance method. For the sake of readability and future maintenance, however, I generally prefer a simple function over the creation of mundane classes.

Comment: Because [LBYL](https://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-lbyl) isn't exactly pythonic.

Comment: And similarly, `my_list.pop() if len(my_list) > 0 else "default"`. It seems a bit clumsy.

Comment: This is not equivalent to OP's code, since it doesn't correctly handle negative indices.

Comment: The function looks good now, but it doesn't add anything substantial over the inheritance approach I proposed in my question.

Comment: Bare except clause :-(