# Multidimensional Array : index out of range

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I'm learning python and wanted to use multidimensional array like we use in c and researched about it and have written the code but stuck at one place and I don't understand why the error is occurring.

My Code:-

```
a=[]
i=0
for record in tablerows: 
    a.append([])
    rowcells=record.findAll('td')
    for data in rowcells[1:4]:
        a[i].append(data.text)
        i=i+1
        print(a)
```

Error:

> a[i].append(data.text)    IndexError: list index out of range.

On second iteration.
Can you please guide me...?
And I'm doing it right or is there a better way of doing it....?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a default value on index out of range in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574636/getting-a-default-value-on-index-out-of-range-in-python)

Comment: May I see the code for tablerows and rowcells?

Comment: @Javier Lim here is the assignment for tablerows variable.      tablerows=tbody.findAll('tr') and for rowcells the assignment is done itself in for loop which is in the line    rowcells=record.findAll('td')

Comment: What are tbody and record?

Comment: @Javir Lim the assignment for both tablerows and rowcells is correct i have checked it.Only the problem is in the 2d array

Comment: tbody is actually an html table and record is a row in the table

Comment: can you print rowcells inside the loop to see what it is?

Comment: rowcells is actually the data of all the celsl in a row

Comment: I wrote the code without the array first and was working fine

Comment: Ok, try shifting i = i + 1 out of the second loop, into the first after the second loop.

Comment: only the problem is within the 2d array

Comment: checking....just a sec

Comment: yup it solved the problem.......thnx a lot mate!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shift i = i + 1 out of the second loop, like this.

```
a=[]
i=0
for record in tablerows: 
    a.append([])
    rowcells=record.findAll('td')
    for data in rowcells[1:4]:
        a[i].append(data.text)
        print(a)
    i=i+1
```