# Elegant way to return color name based on values

Tags: python

Is there a better way to have a function output a color name depending on the value passed to it? Something more elegant to replace the  `if else` algorithm below.

Also, ideally the colors would come from a standard color map instead of having to manually write each color name in the `if else` statement.

Thanks,

```
def color_from_value(val):
    if val <= 1:
        return 'red'
    elif val < 2:
        return 'blue'
    elif val < 3:
        return 'green'
    .
    .
    .
    else:
        return 'black'
```

Comment: Define a `dict` with your colors as keys and their name as values? (You're still limited to a restricted number of colors, of course, but there is no name for all `256**3` colors, so you're pretty much limited that way anyhow)

Comment: use dict  `colors = {1:'red'}  colors.get(77,'black')`

Comment: Are you trying to map arbitrary numbers to colours (i.e. `1 == red`) or are you looking for a way to get the names of hex/rgb colours. If it's the latter, there's a library that can do that: https://github.com/ubernostrum/webcolors

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacements for switch statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple list, which can be useful for iterating over e.g. matplotlib/pyplot lines. (This doesn't deal with your range/limits though.) For example:

```
colors = ['red','blue','green','black']
i=0
chosen_color = colors[i] # red
```

You could make this a lambda, say, in order to handle the default case (borrowing from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2574659/1021819):

```
color_from_value = lambda i: colors[i] if i < len(colors) else 'black'

assert(color_from_value(0) == 'red')
```

For matplotlib, suppose you want to plot two different data sets:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
colors = ['r','b','g','k']
x = np.linspace(0.0,1.0,11)
y = [2.0*x,x**2 + 1.0]
labels = ['linear','quadratic']
```

Then:

```
for i in range(2):
    plt.plot(x,y[i],color=colors[i],label=labels[i])
_=plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, a simple dictionary is enough:

```
options = {1: 'red',
           2: 'blue',
           3: 'green'}

options[1]

# output: 'red'
```

You can generalize this method by associating a function with each element of the dictionary:

```
def do_red():
    return 'red'

def do_blue():
    return 'blue'

def do_green():
    return 'green'

# map the inputs to the function blocks
options = {1: do_red,
           2: do_blue,
           3: do_green}

options[1]()

# output: 'red'
```

**NOTE**: If you want to have a default value when the key does not exist in the dictionary, you can access it this way:

```
options.get(key, 'black') # or options.get(key, lambda: 'black')()
```

If `key` is not an `options` key then returns `'black'`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary instead?:

```
mapping = {1: 'red',
           2: 'blue',
           3: 'green'}
mapping.get(value, 'black')  # 'black' is default in case requested key is not in mapping
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a file called `color.property`.
the content of this file would be looking like this:

```
[color]
1=red
2=blue
3=green
...
```

then in the code:

```
    import ConfigParser
    import math

    config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
    config.read('color.property')

    def color_from_value(val):
                                  //using floor to get integer. like 2.98->2
       return  config.get('color', math.floor(val))
```

there is no if-else. :)

Comment: You can get a config file from e.g. here https://github.com/k-kawakami/colorfulnet/blob/master/example_data/wikipedia-list-of-colors.txt and just take the line number as the enum