# Python List index out of range even if I provide an alternative value

Tags: python, python-2.7, maya

I'm doing this in Maya, but the core issue is from Python. It all boils down to *why `or` doesn't work in this case* :

```py
>>> a = ["something",]
>>> b = a[1] or "empty"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

---

More details:

I need a file's name without the path and extension, and do actions with that in a variable.
So I thought I could just do `name = basenamde(cmds.file(q=True, sn-True).split(".")[-2] or []`

But when doing it in an empty unsaved scene (which returns nothing when asked the file name it doesn't have), it returns that error. I know I could just declare the variable empty first, then check if the file name exists before assigning it to the variable, but it doesn't sound "elegant" to me. I love short one-liners.

I also have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22685248/10705720) that encourages doing this:

```py
b, = a[1] or "empty"
```

Which I would love to use here, but it doesn't seem to work in Maya 2018 (Python 2.7) with the same error `list index out of range`.

Comment: when `a` is `[]`, `a[1]` will definitely give `IndexError: list index out of range` even `a[0]` will give the same error.

Comment: Sure, but why it can't b return "empty" then ?

Comment: Because the `or` is never evaluated, the exception has already occurred. `a[4:5]` will return an empty list rather than raising an exception, which is why the answer you linked works.

Comment: I thought `or` could be used for that precisely... So I guess I don't have much choice. I tried the other method exactly as in the answer in Maya (py 2.7) but it returns an invalid syntax on `:` from `[4:5]`

Comment: it works on python 3.10 standalone

Comment: The error message comes from not being able to access the [1] postion in list a.

However, a workaround can be:

a = ["something",]
try:
  b = a[1]
except:
  b = "empty"
print(b)

Comment: `or` is working *perfectly fine* in this case. `a[1]` is evaluated first, and that throws the error.